# getSender() is returning burn address

Tags: addresses

I'm not getting the same hash running this function

```
    function getMineDigest(uint256 challenge_number, bytes32 nonce) public view returns (bytes32 digesttest) {
        bytes32 digest = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(challenge_number, msg.sender, nonce));
        return digest;
    }
```

As running this in python

```
web3.solidityKeccak(['bytes32','address','uint256'],[challenge_number, account, nonce])
```

Perhaps "msg.sender" is not the value I anticipate.

To test this I added this function to my contract

```
    function getSender() public view returns (address) {
        return msg.sender;
    }
```

But it is returning '0x000000000000' which menas that either msg.sender is not my metamask account or I'm unfamiliar with more nuances of ethereum.